# Sum up values from 2 columns on each row of a table (div table)

Tags: jquery

I have a table made with the Bootstrap 4 div column system and I want to sum on each row 2 columns in a third column but I receive a value only for the first row. Please help me sum for all the rows in the table.

I try to do this with the following script but I receive value only for the first row.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.row').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var ata = parseFloat($("#ata").text());
    var eta = parseFloat($("#eta").text());
    var at = ata - eta;
    $("#balance").html(at.toFixed(0) + " min")
  })
})
```

HTML:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">Name</div>
        <div class="col-2">Alocated Time</div>
        <div class="col-2">Efective Time</div>
        <div class="col-2">Balance</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-striped">
        <div class="col-6">qwerty</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <div id="eta">500</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <div id="eta">100</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <div id="balance">"here i want to add 100+500 with jquery script"</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>......</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the html table? RIght now is hard to understand the structure and understad what is needed.

Comment: <div class="card">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">Name</div>
        <div class="col-2">Alocated Time</div>
        <div class="col-2">Efective Time</div>
        <div class="col-2">Balance</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-striped">
        <div class="col-6">qwerty</a></div>
        <div class="col-2"><div id="eta">500</div></div>
        <div class="col-2"><div id="eta">100</div></div>
        <div class="col-2"><div id="balance">"here i want to add 100+500 with jquery script"</div></div>
    </div>
    <div>......</div>
</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

salam
when you use the '#' selector, the query contain one element, the first in the page, 
you must use class instead of id,and you can find your cells inside row and use its values

ex:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table >
<tr class="row">
 <td class="val1">
     5
 </td>
 <td class="val2">
     1
 </td>
 <td class="result">
 </td>
</tr>
<tr class="row">
 <td class="val1">
     10
 </td>
 <td class="val2">
     2
 </td>
 <td class="result">
 </td>
</tr>
<button>test</button>

</table>
<script>
 $("button").click(function(){
  $('.row').each(function(){
     var val1 =$(this).find(".val1").text();
     var val2 =$(this).find(".val2").text();
        var ata = parseFloat(val1);
     var eta = parseFloat(val2);
     var at = ata - eta;
        var result = at.toFixed(0) + " min";
     var val2 =$(this).find(".result").text(result);
    });
 });
</script>
```